# "Diagnostics Results" is an invalid value for the window title in window.open function

Tags: javascript, window.open

Did you know?

"Diagnostics Results" is an invalid value for the window title in window.open function

wtf?

Comment: It took me some time to find the question - did you mean "I've tried to window.open(param1,param2,param3), but when I try that, I get the error 'xyz'"? Please try to give us a bit more detail than "it's broken", otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

The window.open function doesn't include a title argument.

You're probably confusing it with the target / name - which doesn't allow a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('about:blank','Diagnostics Results')
```

Works for me. What platform/OS?

Comment: Note though, that this doesn't set the window *title*.

Comment: There is no window "title" in the window.open function. I figured that this might be what the OP meant.